# How to prevent the iPhone from waking up when removing it from charging?

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake, charging

Every time I remove my iPhone from the wireless charging dock, it wakes up. This is very inconvenient, as I have to wait for it to wake up and then close the screen before I can safely put it in my pocket.

Is there a way to disable it?

Note: I'm not talking about Raise to Wake, I've already disabled this feature.

Comment: When I do that with my iPhone 11 waking up literally takes a single second. And you can put it back to sleep with the sleep/wake button in, again literally, one second. You make it sound like it takes minutes to wake. And just because it is awake doesn't mean you **have** to sleep it. Unless it is unlocked and on a home screen it is perfectly fine to put it in your pocket immediately and go about your day, assured that it will go back to sleep in the time you have specified in settings.

Comment: @SteveChambers With my iPhone XS Max it takes 3 seconds - I've just timed it. 3 seconds (+ locking it again) multiplied by many times a day is a lot of wasted time. Also, I want it to be locked when I slide it into my pocket, so that I don't accidentally dismiss/open any notifications in the lock screen.

Comment: When you say "wakes up", what do you mean - that the display switches on or that the phone automatically unlocks itself? Do you use a [Passcode on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204060)?

Comment: I mean that the display switches on, I do have Face ID and a passcode